# How to optimise my php code and get everything to work by itself?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, forms, post

I need help to optimize the data processing for a form i built.

The datas are send using a ajax script on the form page to a processing page.

And here is the code:

```
include('pdo-connect.php'); // This file only contains the connection to my database

$html = htmlspecialchars($_POST['HTML']);
$css = htmlspecialchars($_POST['CSS']);
$javascript = htmlspecialchars($_POST['JAVASCRIPT']);
$php = htmlspecialchars($_POST['PHP']);
$ajax = htmlspecialchars($_POST['AJAX']);
$jquery = htmlspecialchars($_POST['JQUERY']);
$responsive = htmlspecialchars($_POST['RESPONSIVE']);
$sql = htmlspecialchars($_POST['SQL']);
$composer = htmlspecialchars($_POST['COMPOSER']);
$symfony = htmlspecialchars($_POST['SYMFONY']);
$doctrine = htmlspecialchars($_POST['DOCTRINE']);
$twig = htmlspecialchars($_POST['TWIG']);
$agile = htmlspecialchars($_POST['AGILE']);
$git = htmlspecialchars($_POST['GIT']);
$python = htmlspecialchars($_POST['PYTHON']);
$seo = htmlspecialchars($_POST['SEO']);
$rgpd = htmlspecialchars($_POST['RGPD']);
$user = htmlspecialchars($_POST['USER']);

$matieres = array(
    1 => $html,
    $css,
    $javascript,
    $php,
    $ajax,
    $jquery,
    $responsive,
    $sql,
    $composer,
    $symfony,
    $doctrine,
    $twig,
    $agile,
    $git,
    $python,
    $seo,
    $rgpd
);

$insert = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO Resultats(ID_USER, ID_MATIERE, RESULTAT) VALUES (:user, :matiere, :resultat)');

foreach($matieres as $key => $value) {
    $insert->bindParam(':user', $user);
    $insert->bindParam(':matiere', $key);
    $insert->bindParam(':resultat', $value);
    $insert->execute();
}

$feedback = "Your results have been added";

if(isset($feedback) && !empty($feedback)) {

    echo $feedback;

}
```

First, i want to get rid of all the declared variable who contains all the $_POST data.
I need to automate all the variable getting the $_post data so if i add another row in my table i'll not have to add another variable here

I want to build a function that will do the job for me but i don't know how to proceed since everything i tried didn't work.

Every name of the input i need to store have the same name than the row['Name'] in one of my table in my database.

So i think we can do a simple SQL query but i don't succeed to make it work like that.

( i tried to build a foreach function with $_POST too but it didn't work neither )

And then, once this is done, i need to store the variables containing the user inputs in a array, like i did above

note:
The sql query i was talking about is this one:

```
$q = $bdd->query('SELECT Nom FROM Matieres WHERE Active = 1');
while($infos = $q->fetch()) {

    echo $infos['Nom'];

}
```

the foreach kind of works. But when i try to get the key and value into a array things starts to get complicated:

```
$matieres = array();

    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {

        $matieres = array(
            $key => $value
        );

    }

    var_dump($matieres); // print only one key and one value

    print_r($matieres); // same here

    print($matieres); // only print the keyword "array"
```

Meanwhile if i echo the key and the value of each $post in my for each without putting them in a array, i can get every input of the user...

i have found something maybe !

```
$matieres = array();

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {

    array_push($matieres, $value, $key);

}

print_r($matieres); // print an array containing the name of all of the input and the value the user put in it but they all have their own keys ... :(
```

Finally i managed to make my code work !

```
<?php

include('pdo-connect.php');

$results = array();

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {

    array_push($results, $value);

}

$results = array_combine(range(1, count($results)), array_values($results));

array_pop($results);

$user = $_POST['USER'];

$insert = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO Resultats(ID_USER, ID_MATIERE, RESULTAT) VALUES (:user, :matiere, :resultat)');

foreach($results as $key => $value) {
    $insert->bindParam(':user', $user);
    $insert->bindParam(':matiere', $key);
    $insert->bindParam(':resultat', $value);
    $insert->execute();
}
$feedback = "Votre auto-évaluation a bien été envoyé ! Vous allez 

maintenant être redirigé vers l'accueil.";

if(isset($feedback) && !empty($feedback)) {

    echo $feedback;

}

?>
```

Comment: i edited my first message, to answer you

Comment: It's best to edit your question to add more information or corrections instead of adding comments.  Also htmlspecialchars is not needed with PDO, it takes care of escaping and quoting fields for you.

Comment: That's not gonna work cause the way you created the `$matieres array` only has one key, wich is `1`, and on the foreach you tried is having much more than one, since every time it goes again you add +1 key

Comment: @DaveS he posted the comment because i asked a question but then deleted cause it was a stupid question sorry

Comment: Ok i deleted the htmlspecialchars.
But im still stuck with my array. I don't really understand how i should build her within the foreach

Comment: I managed to make my code work!
I updated my question with the working code.

thx guys for the help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the assignment:

```
<?php
$inputs = ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JAVASCRIPT'];
$dirty  = [];

foreach($inputs as $input) {
    $dirty[strtolower($input)] = $_POST[$input] ?? '';
}
```

And then later, you can use named placeholders and just execute the statement with your given array.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO foo (html, css, javascript) VALUES (:html, :css, :javascript)");
$stmt->execute($dirty);
```